# Django Rest Framework get attributes from foreign key's class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

here's my **models**:

```
class Recruteur(models.Model):      
    entrepriseName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    emplacement = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Offre(models.Model):          
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default=0)
    idRecruteur = models.ForeignKey(Recruteur,verbose_name = "idRecruteur", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```

and here's my **api.py**:

```
class VilleViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Offre.objects.values('idRecruteur__emplacement').distinct()
    serializer_class = VilleSerializer
```

**serializers.py**:

```
class EmplacementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Recruteur
        fields = ('emplacement',)

class VilleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    emplacements = EmplacementSerializer(source='idRecruteur', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Offre
        fields = ( 'emplacements',)
```

i was expecting a result like this

[image]

but i got nothing instead ..

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

You get nothing, because there is no `emplacements` field in `Offre` model. I guess, what you want is to get serialized `Recruteur` record, that is referenced by `idRecruteur` field. Try this:

```
class VilleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    idRecruteur = EmplacementSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Offre
        fields = ( 'idRecruteur',)
```

Comment: Still nothing .. but emplacements is what i get from EmplacementSerializer

Comment: @M1rwen Try to replace `Offre.objects.values('idRecruteur__emplacement').distinct()` with `Offre.objects.all()`. After that, does viewset returns something?

Comment: yep it returnes the exact result but i need the distinct in the result

Comment: @M1rwen What database are you using?

Comment: Im using Sqlite

Comment: @M1rwen Quote from Django docs "On PostgreSQL only, you can pass positional arguments (*fields) in order to specify the names of fields to which the DISTINCT should apply". It seems like you can't apply distinct to selected rows on SQLite

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169467/discussion-between-grigoriy-mikhalkin-and-m1rwen).